# Swift function not accepting variable

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift2

The code is written in Swift 2.0. I am doing a little tinkering project for clash of clans. My code is below.

```
enum Resource {
    case gold
    case elixer
    case darkElixer
}

class Avatar {
    var cost, health, damage, space: Int
    var costType: Resource
    init(damage: Int, health: Int, cost: Int, costType: Resource, space: Int){
        self.damage = damage
        self.health = health
        self.cost = cost
        self.costType = costType
        self.space = space
    }
}

class Barbarian: Avatar {
    init() {
        super.init(damage: 44, health: 110, cost: 200, costType: .elixer, space: 1)
    }
}

class Archer: Avatar {
    init() {
        super.init(damage: 22, health: 44, cost: 400, costType: .elixer, space: 1)
    }
}
```

I am trying this function.

```
func troopCost(troop: Avatar, quantity: Int) -> (Int, Resource){
    let rResource = troop.costType
    let rCost = troop.cost * quantity
    return (rCost, rResource)
}
```

When I call the function like this.

```
troopCost(Barbarian, quantity: 2)
```

I get this error.

```
Cannon invoke 'troopCost' with an argument list of type '(Barbarian.Type, quantity: Int)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `troopCost(Barbarian, quantity: 2)`, you are trying to pass the Barbarian **class** itself as the argument.

But your function takes an `Avatar` **instance**. So you must first create an instance.

```
let troop = Barbarian()
troopCost(troop, quantity: 2)
```

Furthermore, you could make `troopCost` into an method on `Avatar`:

```
class Avatar {
    // ...
    func cost(quantity: Int) -> (Int, Resource) {
        return (cost * quantity, costType)
    }
}

let troop = Barbarian()
troop.cost(quantity: 2)
```

And if you make these into `struct`s instead of `class`es, you won't have to write out that long `init` method yourself ;)

Comment: thanks man that was such an easy fix I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: @CodyWeaver if this answered your question, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: how do you accept an answer? Also how would I make them into structs?

Comment: Simply use `struct` instead of `class`. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html). Click the checkmark on the left to accept. You should also go back through your old questions and accept answers if appropriate. More info [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).